# Partial Derivative $x^y$? in terms of x

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative

Hi i have the answer but don't understand so please explain your answer... it should be $-yx^{(y-1)}$

Comment: If you are taking the partial derivative with respect to x, then you are holding y constant.  That means that x^y is basically just a power function with base x.  Thus, you can use the power rule to differentiate it.

Comment: I have no idea where the negative sign in your alleged answer came from.

Comment: so not using logarithm or ln to simplify first

Comment: @Ted it should be correct i'm reading from book

Comment: To compute the $y$ partial, you will need to write the function in terms of $e^u$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The definition of the partial derivative of $x^y$ **with respect to** $x$ is

$$\frac{\partial }{\partial x} x^y = \lim_{h\to 0} \frac{(x+h)^y - x^y}{h}.$$

In this way, we may simply treat $y$ as a constant when differentiating. So,
$$\frac{\partial }{\partial x} x^y = yx^{y-1}$$
for the same reason that
$$\frac{d }{d x} x^n = nx^{n-1}.$$

Answer (score 0):

It should be $\frac{d}{{dx}}\left( {{x^y}} \right) = y{x^{y - 1}}$